# How to connect to the second postgres server running as container on different than standard port in pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

I am running two postgres servers as containers from docker-compose on different ports. In pgAdmin, only standard port mapping 5432:5432 is possible to connect. The second server mapped as 5433:5432 to avoid conflict is impossible to connect. Both server containers are running in separate internal network (intentionally), but both servers + pgAdmin are in the common external network. Other than that, all settings are identical.

docker-compose #1:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    postgres:
        container_name: 'postgres'
        image: postgres
        volumes:
            - ../var/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
            - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
            - POSTGRES_DB=firstdb
        networks:
            - netone
        ports:
            - '5432:5432'
networks:
  netone:
    external:
      name: workspace

volumes:
  postgres:
```

docker-compose #2

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    test-postgres:
        container_name: 'test-postgres'
        image: postgres
        volumes:
            - /var/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
            - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
            - POSTGRES_DB=testdb
        networks:
            - test-network
        ports:
            - '5433:5432'

networks:
  test-network:
    external:
      name: workspace

volumes:
  postgres:
```

Both containers starts with success and running.
[image: docker ps]

When I am trying to connect to the latter server, I am getting this in pgAdmin:
[image: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR]

I have tried to change host to localhost, other ports, change db name, register under different servers groups, start both servers before pgadmin, etc. - no success. I am able to run interactive shell inside "problematic" server container and access postgres without any problem.
Running on Ubuntu. Appreciate any help.

Comment: What network is your pgadmin container running on? What hostname do you use to connect to the first one?

Comment: @IainShelvington all of the containers has the same external network, but it is true the first server + pgadmin has common also internal network. Hostname to connect in pgAdmin is the same for both servers, means the connection to first server is exactly the same except the port value.

Comment: "Connection refused", is there  a firewall in place? "...accepting TCP/IP connections", is `postgresql.conf`  `listen_address` and `port` set up correctly?  "Is the server running...", is the server started?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver as I described, the conditions are indentical for both servers. If there is anything wrong with the settings/servers running/firewall - both servers would have the connection problem, not only the latter one. Only significant difference is port.

Comment: No, what you said is "...even all the other settings are pretty the same".  Since the one instance works and the other doesn't the first thing to do would be to confirm settings.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver sorry for not precise writing, you are right. I have updated the description.

Comment: Hi @jjanes, it put just server settings part of the compose files. There is missing standard config of the file at the beginning and network configuration part in the end.

Comment: are you sure that both the containers are properly running? did you check the logs if there was any issue with the container that isn't working? I

Comment: @NeenadIngole yes I am, I am able to interactive shell into the "problem" container and access postrges without problem.

Comment: Which server container do you consider the "problematic" one?

Comment: can you try connecting the problematic db instance from non-problematic one that is running the pgAdmin? I am guessing there is a problem with network

Answer (score 1):

After another several hours of trying to resolve this problem, I would close it as a definitive pgAdmin problem.

The thing is, that there is no problem in compose definition as well as there is no problem with neither of those two postgres servers running properly on different ports.

As I am able to work with both servers via interactive shell/psql and additionally, I am able to connect to the 5433 server via another client, like Pycharm:
[image]

the problem seems to exist only in pgAdmin when we want to connect two servers on different ports. Even change of the compose setup and connection of both servers + pgAdmin on the same internal network did not help:

[image]

(host/user etc. settings are slightly changed in above pictures against the original description as I was playing a lot with that. Additionally, "Maintenance database" in pgAdmin settings is not the same thing as "Database" in PyCharm settings
of course, if somebody would want to bring up the db name difference. But I can assure you I have tried all variations just t be sure).

Conclusion: Do not use two postgres server with single pgAdmin client.

Answer (score 0):

Both databases are running on port 5432, just in different containers.

Your images says you are trying to connect to port 5433 of host 'postgres'.  But that is not where your test database is running--neither the host nor the port.  You would need to specify the correct port 5432 on the correct host 'test-postgres'.

On the docker host computer, you could also specify 5433 of 'localhost' which would get redirected to 5432 of 'test-postgres'.   Or on a container in the network you could specify 5433 of host 172.17.0.1, which would go out to the host then get redirected back into the correct host of the network on the correct port.

Comment: Hi, sorry, but I don't think you are right.  "Both databases are running on port 5432, just in different containers." - yes of course, postgres is (as default) always run on port 5432. That's why there is a possibility to map external port of the container to internal port of the app running in container in case there is 2 containers with app using the same port. To avoid the conflict, I am mapping internal 5432 port of both containers to 5432 in first case and 5433 in second case, so I have two servers running listening to different ports but routing to same internal port of postgres db.

Comment: The mapping doesn't happen within the container, it happens on the docker daemon, *between* the docker host and the container.  If you are using the network you created and specifying the container name as the host name, this bypasses the mapping.  And it is unnecessary to use different ports, as they already use different host names.  I'm not speculating, I've actually done the set up and verified it works as I describe (although I used psql not pgAdmin to test the connections)

Comment: I really appreciate your effort to trying to setup it on your own and find the problem. But that's exactly I stated above. I have no problem with my setup to connect to both containers and working with both databases via using psql. We are talking about pgAdmin problem here, not the containers setup.